# I have three drop down button I want to click the specific dropdown and pop up the list and display on the that specific click dropdown , not in all

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have three drop down button that I style them using the same class. When I click any of them it pops up a list where I select any list under the dropdown and display it on the button.

The problem is that it's displaying in all of the three dropdowns even though I focus on the specific drop down and I am voiding to have along code by changing each an every dropdown an ID and target on it. If there's away to do it may you please help.

```css
.dropdownbox>button {
  color: #7C99AA;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #7C99AA;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  width: 10vw;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 8vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background: white;
  color: #9FA5B5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5px 20;
  position: absolute;
}

ul.menu li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0.7em 0em;
  margin: -0.3em 0;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #7C99AA;
}

.menu.showMenu {
  height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapCollect3">
  <div class="dropdownbox">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="penaltybtn">Select</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu3" class="menu">
    <li id="applicc">Not Applicable</li>
    <li id="appYes">Yes</li>
    <li id="appNo">No</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdownbox">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="offboarding">Select</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu1" class="menu">
    <li name="offboarding" id="resignation">Resignation</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="contract">Contract Expiration</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="retrenchment">Retrenchment</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="dismissal">Dismissal</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="retirement">Retirement</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="collecWrap">
  <div class="dropdownbox">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">Collected</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu2" class="menu">
    <li id="returnNot" value="NotReturned">Not Returned</li>
    <li id="majority" value="majority">Majority Returned</li>
    <li id="all">All Returned</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
$('.dropdownbox').click(function() {
  $('.menu').hide();
  $(this).next('.menu').show();
});
```

I've also changed your css a little bit. I've removed `height:0px` from ul.menu and added `display:none;`

```js
$('.dropdownbox').click(function() {
  $('.menu').hide();
  $(this).next('.menu').show();
});
```

```css
.dropdownbox>button {
  color: #7C99AA;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #7C99AA;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  width: 10vw;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 8vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background: white;
  color: #9FA5B5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}

ul.menu li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0.7em 0em;
  margin: -0.3em 0;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #7C99AA;
}

.menu.showMenu {
  height: 20vh;
}

.wrapper,.wrapCollect3,.collectWrap{

    display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapCollect3">
  <div class="dropdownbox">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="penaltybtn">Select</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu3" class="menu">
    <li id="applicc">Not Applicable</li>
    <li id="appYes">Yes</li>
    <li id="appNo">No</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdownbox">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="offboarding">Select</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu1" class="menu">
    <li name="offboarding" id="resignation">Resignation</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="contract">Contract Expiration</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="retrenchment">Retrenchment</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="dismissal">Dismissal</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="retirement">Retirement</li>
  </ul>
</div>




<div class="collecWrap">
  <div class="dropdownbox">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">Collected</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu2" class="menu">
    <li id="returnNot" value="NotReturned">Not Returned</li>
    <li id="majority" value="majority">Majority Returned</li>
    <li id="all">All Returned</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort but its still doing the same thing on my side.

Comment: @Nyikiwe I can't tell you what's going on your side, but you could check the console for errors. Have you included jquery?

Comment: Yes i did, it is only open the drop down list and i want to select any list on the drop downs and display it on the specific button not in all of them

Comment: @Nyikiwe That is not an error but a request. From the code provided you should be able to find a good way to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

You are not too clear in your answer, and you are providing no working code,
But If I get it, you need to show on the button the text you click in the submenu, like "emulating a select".

It's quite easy.

So, on the 3 main parents add a class

```
<div class="wrapCollect3 buttonParent">
[...]
<div class="wrapper buttonParent">
[...]
<div class="collecWrap buttonParent">
```

In js, add a function to retrieve them on click

```
function getParentByClass(el, className, maxDepth=10) {
  let i=0;
  while (!el.classList.contains(className)) {
    el=el.parentElement;
    i++;
    if (i>maxDepth) return false;
  }
  return el;
}
```

call it like this:

```
// In your onclick function, 
// given "el" as the clicked submenu button
let parent = getParentByClass(el, "buttonParent")
```

Now find the button inside the buttonParent of the clicked submenu, and set its text as the text you clicked in the submenu

```
parent.querySelector('button').innerText = el.getText();
```

Now you just need to fix the "hide" submenu when you click outside the submenu. I leave this exercise to you, because this is not "code solution" website, and we are here always to learn! Cheers!

```js
/// Taken from Carsten Løvbo Andersen answer
$('.dropdownbox').click(function() {
  $('.menu').hide();
  $(this).next('.menu').show();
});

//// Maybe there is some jquery version, but this is universal
/// this find parent by class name, giving a depth in search too
function getParentByClass(el, className, maxDepth=10) {
  let i=0;
  while (!el.classList.contains(className)) {
    el=el.parentElement;
    i++;
    if (i>maxDepth) return false;
  }
  return el;
}

document.querySelectorAll("ul.menu li").forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(c){
    let li = c.target;
    let t = li.innerText;
    let p = getParentByClass(li, 'parentButton');
    p.querySelector('button').innerText = t;
    $('.menu').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdownbox>button {
  color: #7C99AA;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #7C99AA;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  width: 10vw;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 8vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background: white;
  color: #9FA5B5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}

ul.menu li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0.7em 0em;
  margin: -0.3em 0;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #7C99AA;
}

.menu.showMenu {
  height: 20vh;
}

.wrapper,.wrapCollect3,.collectWrap{

    display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapCollect3 parentButton">
  <div class="dropdownbox">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="penaltybtn">Select</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu3" class="menu">
    <li id="applicc">Not Applicable</li>
    <li id="appYes">Yes</li>
    <li id="appNo">No</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="wrapper parentButton">
  <div class="dropdownbox">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="offboarding">Select</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu1" class="menu">
    <li name="offboarding" id="resignation">Resignation</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="contract">Contract Expiration</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="retrenchment">Retrenchment</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="dismissal">Dismissal</li>
    <li name="offboarding" id="retirement">Retirement</li>
  </ul>
</div>




<div class="collecWrap parentButton">
  <div class="dropdownbox">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">Collected</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu2" class="menu">
    <li id="returnNot" value="NotReturned">Not Returned</li>
    <li id="majority" value="majority">Majority Returned</li>
    <li id="all">All Returned</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help the functionality part I did added it ,I don't know what happen when I submit. the problem that I was having is that when I click on the button collected and click any list from it ,it was displaying the list of collected to the other two button.

Comment: If the answered problem is solved, please close the question accepting the answer. It's impossible to know what happen to your side because you didn't provide any js code. 
The code you provided just show the menu but doesn't manage any click.